# I Have got List of workers and menager in list wchich I read by REST API

Tags: rest, spfx, spfx-webparts

What Should I Write in declarations and in return code to get this users name and photos. Here is REST returns:

[image]

What should I change to get users name and surnames and photo os users ?

And here is  my code of webpart:

```
  private _getMockListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
    return MockHttpClient.get()
      .then((data: ISPList[]) => {
        var listData: ISPLists = { value: data };
        return listData;
      }) as Promise<ISPLists>;
  }

  private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('KomorkaOrganizacyjna')/(1)?$select=Title,MPK,Skrot,Informacje_o_komorce,Kierownik/Title,Menadzer_zarzadzaacy/Title,Lista_Pracownikow/Title&$expand=Kierownik,Menadzer_zarzadzaacy,Lista_Pracownikow", SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json();
      });
  }
  
  private _renderList(items: ISPList[]): void {
    let html: string = '';
    items.forEach((item: ISPList) => {
      html += `
      <div style="color: #000000;"> 
      <div>
        <strong>Nazwa działu:</strong><span> ${item.Title}</span> 
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <strong>MPK działu:</strong><span> ${item.MPK}</span> 
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <strong>Przełożony:</strong><span> ${item.Prze_x0142_o_x017c_onyId}</span>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
      <strong>Skrócona nazwa działu:</strong><span> ${item.Skrot}</span> 
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <strong>Kierownik:</strong><span> ${item.KierownikId}</span> 
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <strong>Manadzer zarządzający:</strong><span> ${item.Menadzer_zarzadzaacyId}</span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <strong>Lista pracowników:</strong><span> ${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid("+item.Lista_PracownikowId+")"}</span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
        <div>
          <h2>Krótkie informacje o Komórce Organizacyjnej</h2>
          <p> ${item.Informacje_o_komorce}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You cannot get profile picture in single call using `/items` endpoint.

Comment: So what Should i do ?

Comment: here is my whole link of Rest Api:
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('KomorkaOrganizacyjna')/(1)?$select=Title,MPK,Skrot,Informacje_o_komorce,Kierownik/Title,Menadzer_zarzadzaacy/Title,Lista_Pracownikow/Title&$expand=Kierownik,Menadzer_zarzadzaacy,Lista_Pracownikow"

Comment: As I said in your earlier question, you will need multiple REST calls for this.

Comment: Yes I know, but how do this. Please help Ganesh Sonap?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fetch-user-details-and-profile-picture-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api/). let me know if it works for you.

Comment: So I need write this ?  var Query = Select + Sort + Filter;  
        $.ajax({  
            url: ListUrl + Query,  
            method: "GET",  
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },  
            success: function (data) {  
                if (data.d != undefined) {  
                    var KeyContactsHTML = "";  

But if I had 3 users I should do this 3 times ?

Comment: I had write this Rest Link and I got access deny:
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('KomorkaOrganizacyjna')/Items(1)?$select=Title,MPK,Skrot,Informacje_o_komorce,Prze_x0142_o_x017c_ony/Title,Kierownik/Title,Lista_Pracownikow/Title&$expand=Prze_x0142_o_x017c_ony/Id,Kierownik/Id,Lista_Pracownikow/Id